# How many groups can we create on Salesforce chatter?

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups

What is the maximum number of groups that we could create on Salesforce chatter? Does this count has any relation with the number of chatter licenses that an Organization holds.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a maximum of 10K chatter groups in an org. There is no relationships between Chatter licenses and group number.

More details on this Chatter limits

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_collaboration.htm&language=en_US